# Exception Eventlistener is not catching Exceptions from RabbitMQ consumer

Tags: php, symfony, error-handling, rabbitmq, consumer

I'm creating a Microservice in Symfony where I need to use RabbitMQ to consume messages to create a document. The consumer is working but whenever a Exception is thrown I want to log the Exception in a format and in a separate log file.

I'm using Symfony 4.2 and all Exceptions that are thrown are logged in the dev.log. I made a new channel in Monolog and called in exception, so that I can manage my loggings.

For this manner I am using an ExceptionListener and I followed the instructions from the Symfony Docs.

I have my Consumer setup as follows

```php
public function execute(AMQPMessage $msg): int
    {
        try {
            return $this->documentService->createDocument($this->serializer->deserialize($msg->body, 'array', 'json'));
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
             $this->logger->error($e);

            return ConsumerInterface::MSG_REJECT;
        }
    }
```

And inside the service I have the following:

```php
try {
...

    $template = $this->templateRepository->findOneByName($messageData['template']);
    if ($template === null) throw new \Exception('Template does not exist');

...

    return ConsumerInterface::MSG_ACK;
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    $this->logger->error($e);

    return ConsumerInterface::MSG_REJECT;
}
```

Im logging on both classes but when an Exceptions throws I get the Exception in the console but the Listener does not catches the ExceptionEvent.

I have tried different events and I added http-kernel package to the Symfony, since I am using Symfony Flex I don't have all packages.

I have registered my Listener in services.yaml as following:

```
    App\EventListener\DocumentExceptionListener:
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.exception, method: onKernelException }
        arguments:
            $logger: '@monolog.logger.exception' # Log all exceptions to a separate log file
```

And my ExceptionListener is as following:

```php
public function __construct(LoggerInterface $logger, SerializerInterface $serializer)
    {
        $this->logger = $logger;
        $this->serializer = $serializer;

        $this->logger->info('Starting to listen...');
    }

    public function onKernelException(GetResponseForExceptionEvent $event)
    {
        $this->logger->info('currently listening...');

        $this->log($event->getException());
    }

    private function log(\Exception $exception)
    {
        $log = [
            'code' => $exception->getCode(),
            'message' => $exception->getMessage(),
            'called' => [
                'file' => $exception->getTrace()[0]['file'],
                'line' => $exception->getTrace()[0]['line'],
            ],
            'occurred' => [
                'file' => $exception->getFile(),
                'line' => $exception->getLine(),
            ],
        ];

        if ($exception->getPrevious() instanceof Exception) {
            $log += [
                'previous' => [
                    'message' => $exception->getPrevious()->getMessage(),
                    'exception' => get_class($exception->getPrevious()),
                    'file' => $exception->getPrevious()->getFile(),
                    'line' => $exception->getPrevious()->getLine(),
                ],
            ];
        }

        $this->logger->error($this->serializer->serialize($log, 'json'));
    }
```

My output right now is:

```
exception.INFO: Starting to listen... [] []
```

Comment: Since you already catch the exception in your service, the second catch block (in your consumer) is never used. From what it looks like, you only use your custom logger in the Consumer and since the catch block is not called, it will never be used.

Comment: The ExceptionListener is not used either, as you catch the Exception before it can be handled by the listener. Either you have to re-throw the exception or ensure that your service already uses the new logger

Comment: I've updated my code and I removed the Try Catch statements on my Service and from my Consumer... And the Listener still doesn't catches.

Comment: Even when I add a throw at the first line of the functions my Listener doesn't enter the onKernelException method

Comment: It could be that your listener has the wrong priority. if there is another listener with a higher priority, that adds a response to the event, the event propagation is stopped. Try checking `bin/console debug:event-dispatcher kernel.exception`

Comment: My Listener is on top and should be fired as first one. I added console.error event to the listener and removed the TryCatch from my Service. This worked for me but the Consumer stops working after the Service 'throws' the Exceptions back to the consumer

Comment: Yes, the ExceptionListener will only work for exceptions that are not caught inside the application. Whenever you catch them it will not trigger. Maybe instead of having the ExceptionListener try something like `$this->logger->log($e->getMessage(), ['exception' => $e]);` this will log the message and the full stack trace without needing a special listener

Answer (score 0):

I read the word "console" in your question. 
If it is a console exception (because it is about a command execution) you have to tag your listener another way:

```
tags:
    - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: console.error }
```

See the `console.error` event name here.

See more here: [Events and Event Listeners](https://symfony.com/doc/current/event_dispatcher.html)